The way to create Path for Flask in anaconda prompt and and windows command
Flask Installation completed in my Windows 10 Laptop. Now What's the  Next Step.
My Python Version Python 3.11.5,  Flask 2.0.0, Werkzeug 2.2.3, ) C:\Users\DELL>,
flask installation completed need further assistance for to start work with windows10

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Create a python file named app.py inside of which write the code
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

After that set the environment variables, these are to be done in command line interface in directory where flask is installed.
set FLASK_APP=app
set FLASK_ENV=development

Run the flask project
flask run


This is the error occurred after this step.
(my_env) C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\LAMRA\flask-app>set FLASK_APP=app
(my_env) C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\LAMRA\flask-app>set FLASK_ENV=development
(my_env) C:\Users\DELL\OneDrive\LAMRA\flask-app>flask run
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.
Error: Could not import 'app'.
